# Skip Windows SBS 2011 installation wizard / install products separately, without initial configuration

Tags: windows-sbs-2011

**Hello,**

As we know, Windows Small Business Server 2011 is a package of:

- Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard,
- Exchange Server 2010,
- SharePoint Foundation 2010.

After first part of installation where Windows is installed, we've got wizard which will allow/force us to configure some essentials settings like time, networking, domain name etc, and also installs rest of the components. This wizard is present only in SBS, not in regular Windows Server version.

---

**Is it possible to skip this wizard and end up with clean Windows 2008 R2 system without any imposed configuration on it?**

---

I know what I want to have, so I don't want to mess with some roles installed or some settings set immediately after setup. I want clean Windows 2008 R2 setup which would allow me to promote it to domain controller manually, install Exchange etc.

---

Thank you,
SV

Answer (score 2):

Not with SBS2011, it comes as a package you have to install it as such and then configure it's roles afterwards. If you wish to have a base 2008 Server R2 install you'll need to purchase the Premium add-on (which is intended to be ran as a HyperV host for SBS).